# Tracing Along Line From A Point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, select, waterways

I have a set of point features which have been snapped to a waterways polyline feature class.

I need to select the waterways where they are within 6km upstream or downstream of any given point and create a new feature class from this selection. I do only have a basic licence on ArcMap 10.3.

I've looked a bit into routes and linear referencing but thus far haven't seen a way that work for what I want, and the waterways feature class isn't currently formatted as a route so any way I can avoid converting it would be ideal.

Comment: Are you familiar with Select by Location, create feature from selection and buffering?

Comment: I considered selecting by location, but I need the 6km distance to follow the stream, so it would almost never be a straight line and I don't think Select by Location has an option to trace a specific line feature to determine distance.

Comment: Is your river a single line or true network with tributaries?

Comment: It's a dataset of watercourse segments, they're all connected but not stored as a true network.

Comment: RivEX can generate the u/s and d/s reaches and can deal with tributaries and multi-threaded sections, all of which your solution will have to deal with. Have a look at the help file [here](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Creatingreaches.html).

Answer (score 1):

It appears your solution would be to do the following:

You can set the points and distance along your line to then create the buffer to select those waterways in your area.

You could use the [Create Points from Lines](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-new-points-along-a-line.htm)

> Construct Points creates new point features at intervals along a selected line. For instance, you could use Construct Points to place utility poles along an electric line. You can create a specific number of points that are evenly spaced, or you can create points at an interval you choose based on distances or m-values.

There are three options you could use:

First option

Number of points—A specific number of points are created along the selected line so they are evenly spaced. In this example, two points, evenly spaced, are created on the line.

[image]

Two points created on the line

Second option

> Distance—The points are created on the selected line based on an interval that is measured in map units from either the start or end of the line. Arrows are shown to indicate the direction of the selected line. In this case, the line starts at the left and ends at the right.

[image]

> Arrows are shown to indicate the direction of the line

Third option

> By measures (m-values)–The points are created on the selected line based on an interval that is measured in m-values from either the start or end of the line. To use this option, the line must have m-values, and they must be in order (consistently increasing or consistently decreasing) to be valid.

Alternatively, this may be another approach

Take your point features and [create a buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) to the 6 km area of interest you have set.

[image]

Then use the [select by location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm):

[image]

[image]

Then you could [create a feature from selection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/working-with-selected-features.htm)

[image]

Also, if you wanted to [export to data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/exporting-features.htm) your selected feature files you can by:

- Right-click the layer in the table of contents and click Data > Export Data.
- Click the Export arrow and click All features, Selected features, or All
  features in View Extent.
- Click the option for the output coordinate system you want to use.
- Click the browse button Browse and navigate to a location to save the exported data.
- Type the name for the output data source.
- Click the Save as type arrow and choose the output type.
- Click Save.
- Click OK.

Comment: I definitely considered this, but I need the distance to follow the waterways feature class, not just a 6km straight radius from each point, but rather 6km upstream or downstream following the rivers.

Comment: I've updated my response to include creating points from a line, they using the other steps subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split line and set the distance to 6km:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-at-a-specified-distance-or-percentage.htm